# How to write a postgres function that returns a set of rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Mainly I am looking for implementing some kind of stored views/reports but with parameters so you can easily update them.

I tried to folow the instructions from http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions but so far I wasn't able to get a list of results back.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myreport(in TEXT) returns setof TEXT AS
$$

   select * from ... where ... = '$1'

$$
language sql;

select * from myreport('XOP');
```

While the internal SQL works well and returns the desired results, it seems that the function execution returns only one item, instead of a list of rows (in my case the select returns a single text column).

Comment: See [return next](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) in the documentation.

Comment: @greg That is for `plpgsql`

Answer (score 1):

Take the quotes out from the parameter:

```
select * from ... where ... = $1
```

But that returns all columns in instead of a single text column as declared in the function definition (`setof text`). It should be:

```
select text_col from ... where ... = $1
```

Or if you want all columns declare it as returning a `setof the_table`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myreport(in TEXT) returns setof the_table AS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return several lines using the TABLE return type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION plop() RETURNS TABLE (value int) AS $sql$
    SELECT generate_series(1, 10) AS value;
$sql$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM plop();
┌───────┐
│ value │
├───────┤
│     1 │
│     2 │
│     3 │
   ...
│    10 │
└───────┘
```